# Most efficient way to cross compare millions of hash values in a list

Tags: python, list, hash, time-complexity

I have a list of 9 million hash values. I need to compare each value(hash0) in the list with the rest of the values :

```
for i, hash0 in enumerate(hashes_list):
    for hash1 in hashes_list[i:]:
       if hash0 -hash1 < threshold:
          #do something
```

This solution above is of quadratic complexity, which is taking forever to run (even in a server). What is an efficient way to cross-match these 9 million hashes?

Here is a sample of the hashes_list values :

```
8c59ac5169e673a6
ab9f545497b05683 
9590ee98373e1e19 
c1274a5e1e150e7f
938f7c782dc6241b
```

Comment: Two things come to mind. First parallelize your script. Second, try to find a way to to reduce the values to compare against aka don't waste time on comparing hash values that obviously don't match. In a database, it can do this with indexes. Like let's say it's strings, only compare strings with other strings that start with the same letter. But for that, need to know how are you actually comparing these hash values. Can you explain more what you are doing in line ```if hash0 -hash1 < threshold:```? What data types are your hash0 and threshold variables?

Comment: I tried to take the first three hegadicimal characters of the hash key as a string , and do the first comparison based on these first, but this didn't optimise the time at all. Regarding the hashing, they are a result of perceptual hashing of jpg images (type=imagehash.ImageHash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the subtraction is just a regular subtraction, try sorting first, Sorts can be O(n Ln(n)) time complexity which is a little better than n^2

That way you could iterate once with two pointers finding groups of hashes that are all close to each other. This would be n*k complexity with n being the number of hashes and k being the average number that match.

The pseudo code would look something like

```
sort(hashes_list) #large to small
count = size(hashes_list)
i = 0
while i < count:
     j = i + 1
     while hashes_list[i] - hashes_list[j] < threshold:
         #do something
         j += 1
     i += 1
```

you might be able to skip the check in some cases. For example where 0 - 10 all are within the threshold, then 1-10 would also be and the "#do something" would just have to be called for each without another check

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to compare exact matches of your values, that rules out easily using sets or dicts -

but you can certainly benefit from using a better data structure that could be more fit for the purpose.

If the value comparison you need is numeric, as it seems in your code, it looks like simply sorting the list (and sorting 9 million values is quite feasible), and comparing the neighbors in the result could suffice to reduce your complexity from O(n**2) to O(n).